# Pod cannot find mount path on Docker Desktop(Win)

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

On Docker Desktop(Win, open file sharing already), create pv/pvc and bound successfully, but start pod failed shows:

```
Warning  Failed     4s (x4 over 34s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Error: stat /c/cannot-found: no such file or directory
```

Have already created the "cannot-found" folder on my root which path is `C:\cannot-found`
Here are my pv/pvc and pod yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: global-volume
  labels:
    pv_pvc_label: nfs
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi  
  hostPath:
    path: "/c/cannot-found"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: standard

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: global-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pv_pvc_label: nfs
  volumeName: global-volume
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: alpine
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: centos
      module: centos      
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: centos
        module: centos
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: nfs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: global-volume
      containers:
      - image: centos
        command:
          - /bin/sh
          - "-c"
          - "touch /root/test.txt; echo \"test mount\">/root/test.txt; cp /root/test.txt /tmp/test.txt; sleep 60m"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: alpine
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nfs
          mountPath: /tmp
          subPath: mountPath
      restartPolicy: Always
```

My pv/pvc status:

```
leih@CNleih01 MINGW64 /c/dev/SAW/x-workspace/deployers/common (leih/workspace)
$ kubectl create -f global-volume-tmp.yaml
persistentvolume/global-volume created
persistentvolumeclaim/global-volume created

leih@CNleih01 MINGW64 /c/dev/SAW/x-workspace/deployers/common (leih/workspace)
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME            STATUS    VOLUME          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
global-volume   Pending   global-volume   0                         standard       7s

leih@CNleih01 MINGW64 /c/dev/SAW/x-workspace/deployers/common (leih/workspace)
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME            STATUS   VOLUME          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
global-volume   Bound    global-volume   1Gi        RWX            standard       10s

leih@CNleih01 MINGW64 /c/dev/SAW/x-workspace/deployers/common (leih/workspace)
$ kubectl scale deployment alpine --replicas=1
deployment.apps/alpine scaled

leih@CNleih01 MINGW64 /c/dev/SAW/x-workspace/deployers/common (leih/workspace)
$ kubectl get po |grep alpine
alpine-6559ddcb88-n262l                       0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          14s

leih@CNleih01 MINGW64 /c/dev/SAW/x-workspace/deployers/common (leih/workspace)
$ kubectl describe po alpine-6559ddcb88-n262l |grep Error
      Reason:       CreateContainerConfigError
  Warning  Failed     4s (x4 over 34s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Error: stat /c/cannot-found: no such file or directory
```

File sharing:
[image]

k8s version: v1.16.6-beta.0

docker desktop version(win): [Docker Desktop Community 2.3.0.2](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2302)

docker version: v19.03.8

How can I solve it?

---

Update:

After rollback docker desktop from v2.3.0.2 to v2.2.0.5, it works fine.

Comment: "/c/cannot-found" this path, does it exist in your file sharing? and just to be clear are you creating /c/cannot-found on your root?

Comment: I created a folder named "cannot-found" where at my root folder and my platform is windows, so the path is "C:\cannot-found", my file sharing is my whole "C:\"

Comment: but in the pv you are giving it as "/c/cannot-found", while you create on root, i-e "C:\cannot-found" NOT C:\c\cannotfound

Comment: can you change path in pv as "C:\cannot-found"

Comment: I tried, same error. Btw, after rollback docker desktop version(from latest to second), `/c/cannot-found ` can work.

Comment: Should be the latest docker desktop issue